# What is the meaning of mešeq in Genesis 15:2?

Tags: hebrew, genesis, hapax-legomenon

In Genesis 15:2, as Abram laments his childlessness to the LORD, he says,

> and the heir of my house is Eliezer of Damascus <sub>([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Genesis%2015%3A2/))</sub>
>   וּבֶן־מֶ֣שֶׁק בֵּיתִ֔י ה֖וּא דַּמֶּ֥שֶׂק אֱלִיעֶֽזֶר
>  
>   ûb̲en–mešeq bêt̲î hûʾ dammeśeq ʾĕlîʿezer

This word *mešeq* (“and the son of the *mešeq* of the house of me”) was one I didn’t know, and it sounds oddly like *dammeśeq* three words later, albeit with different sibilation. I looked it up and found (HALOT, transliteration added):

> SamP.<sup>M137</sup> māšaq, Sept. Μασεκ: בֵּיתִי בֶּן מֶשֶׁק (*bêt̲î ben mešeq*), subsequently glossed with הוּא דַמֶּשֶׂק (*hûʾ d̲ammeśeq*) Gn 15<sub>2</sub>; unexplained., ? Ug. *mšq* (Gordon Textbook §19:1565), most recently: Seebass ZAW 75:317ff; Dahood *Ug.-Heb. Phil.* 65. †

This seems to be an entry without an English gloss. It does include a transliteration into Greek and notation that this is its only usage in the Hebrew bible (two remarkably unhelpful bits of information), and then a lot of other things I don’t understand. There is a connection made with d̲ammeśeq, but I’m not sure what “subsequently glossed with” means here. In the LXX it looks to have been interpreted as a name.

- What does *mešeq* mean?
- Is there a connection with *d̲ammeśeq*?

Answer (score 4):

It's worth reading Gesenius's interpretation of מֶשֶׁק [here](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H4943&t=KJV). He identifies מֶשֶׁק *(mesheq)* with מֶשֶׁךְ (*meshek* - defined [here](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H4901&t=KJV)) in its meaning of "possession." He views the unusual form of מֶשֶׁק, with a *koph* instead of a *caph* for the last letter, as a pun ("paronomasia") to go with with דַּמֶּשֶׂק *(Dammeseq),* "Damascus."

Gesenius rejects the interpretation in which בֶן־מֶשֶׁק (*ben-mesheq* - literally "son of mesheq," but using "son" as a Hebrew idiom for "one characterized by or connected with" - see the list of definitions [here](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H1121&t=KJV)) would mean "steward" (used in, for example, the KJV) as making no sense in the context. Instead, he reads it as "possessor of my house, i.e., of my domestic property," meaning *heir* of his household possessions. This is how it is interpreted in many recent translations.

This interpretation makes sense in context because Abram is lamenting his childlessness, which would mean that he lacked a proper heir.

See the first link above for more detail.

Comment: I don't see the point of digging up a very old dictionary to contradict a modern one. There is such a thing as progress, even in Biblical studies.

Comment: @fdb I wasn't intending to contradict, but to offer a possible meaning and derivation of the word. Most modern translations do seem to interpret it along the lines that Gesenius suggested. However, if you have a better answer based on more modern dictionaries, please do write up a new answer. I would be very interested to see it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I would like to connect the words

- שק
- נשק
- משק

[שק] is translated as "sack cloth" in your English Bibles. However, I would like to propose that [שק] more akin to cheap fabrics used as undergarments such as *loincloth*. Therefore, [שק] is material/entity that is close/intimate to you out of convenience. Someone or something conveniently place in intimacy. And therefore, implements like a pouch that is made out of cheap underwear materials.

[נשק] is an ancient Semitic word, which means to touch, to kiss. Consequently, it means implements that are used to touch you, like a weapon. Perhaps, in ancient times *to touch someone* is an idiomatic euphemism of *assaulting someone*.

[משק] seems like the hifil causative form, *caused to be intimate*. Hence the participle [משק] - someone who is made an intimate member of the household. Like a servant, an adoptive person.

[ד] is often used in Aramaic to denote placing, position. Perhaps, it is an old pre-Assyrian prefix inherited by Aramaic.

Therefore my hypothesis says that

> ובן משק ביתי
>   and the son of the intimate-adoptive-member of my household
>    הוא דמשק אליעזר
>   is one placed in intimacy Eliezer.

That is Abraham is moaning that his current closest person to inherit his heritage/materials is someone not biologically related to him.

Perhaps Damshiq/Dameseq (Arabic/Hebrew/Aramaic for Damascus) is the little village from which the [דמשק] originated.

Comment: The fact that Damascus existed as a city, demonstrated the must have been pervasiveness of the story of Abraham and Eliezer. That is to say, linguistic paleontological evidence for the existence of Abraham and the factual prominence of legacy of Abraham even among the Assyrians that a city was founded out of the birthplace of his adoptive kin.

Comment: Is this your own folk etymology, or is there some specific scholarship (dictionaries, linguistic studies, etc.) to back it up? If the latter, some references would be helpful to give your answer weight.

Comment: "folk etymology"? Using the word "folk" is a cunning way to sweep aside a theological argument based on Hebrew word analysis. Certainly, some of the opinions you read and accept, too are "folk" analogy that got accepted, which you never bothered to question.

Comment: I'm sorry to have given offense. However, I am still interested in an answer to my question. Your answer seems to be written as a personal opinion and interpretation.

Comment: Is no less valid than other opinions which likewise depend on conjectures. At least my conjecture is based on the usual common Hebrew grammatical patterns and inflections.